# How to read JSON data from a web server running PHP and MySQL?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I read example in http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_example.asp.

And I try it with my MySQL database and my PHP code. But it does not work. 
I am a beginner and I don't know what it wrong.

Here is my PHP link: http://xebus2014.tk/demo.php

And I change w3school code like this:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>
h1 {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #cc9900;
    color: #996600;
    font-size: 30px;
}
table, th , td  {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 5px;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Customers</h1>
<div id="id01"></div>

<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://xebus2014.tk/demo.php";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;
    var out = "<table>";

    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += "<tr><td>" + 
        arr[i].STT +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].ID +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].Name +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].Singer +
        "</td></tr>";
    }
    out += "</table>"
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: PHP code]

Comment: Also post your php code. Don't put the php in a snippet (as it won't work)

Comment: what is your error message

Comment: You don't need to parse the response as it's already JSON. This is probably the error.

Comment: I executed the code and it worked correctly. I have used PHP as below     <?php
echo '[{"STT":"1","ID":"123","Name":"Sexy Love","Singer":"T-ara"},{"STT":"2","ID":"456","Name":"Day By Day","Singer":"T-ara"},{"STT":"3","ID":"789","Name":"Cry Cry","Singer":"T-ara"}]';
?>

Comment: Your code is fine, but you may encounter cross domain issues if the page does not come from the same domain xebus2014.tk unless you implemented [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: If you are running html script from another server then you can face this kind of issue. This is also suggested by @laruiss

Comment: It does not print my database. @Astro

Comment: I just add my php code @SuperDJ.Thanks for your help

Comment: if you console the response value?? First check whether the data is retrived from the php file...so console the response...and rest of the code was fine @nistelrooy41001662

Comment: mention header type at your php file

Comment: Console error: "ReferenceError: header is not defined". Not response value @Astro

Comment: so simple just mention your header type at your php code....for your reference check the w3schools link you have shared

Comment: I add header in my php. And now cosole reponse "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://xebus2014.tk/demo.php. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)." @Astro

Comment: reading from the latest error, you need to have both your html and the php code to be on the same server. "Cross-Origin Request Blocked:" is javascripts way of telling you that you are trying to read files from another server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set the response as Json String?

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

Comment: I add header in my php code. But it still dose not display data.

Answer (score 1):

Your result is already an object, so you don't need to parse it using JSON.parse, just use it as is and pass it through the loop as is.

I don't know about the cross domain issue, but to run it, I go directly to your function... see this fiddle for a working loop using your output -- http://jsfiddle.net/fu3g5Loe/

OR you may use this in your PHP backend

```
echo json_encode('Your result set goes here'); // this will apply the correct JSON representation of your result set before echoing
```

Working Code

```
<body>

<h1>Customers</h1>
<div id="id01"></div>

<script>
    /*
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://xebus2014.tk/demo.php";

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    */

    var params = [{"STT":"1","ID":"123","Name":"Sexy Love","Singer":"T-ara"},{"STT":"2","ID":"456","Name":"Day By Day","Singer":"T-ara"},{"STT":"3","ID":"789","Name":"Cry Cry","Singer":"T-ara"}];

    myFunction(params);

function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = response;

    var i;
    var out = "<table>";

    for(i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {  
    out += "<tr><td>" + 
        arr[i].STT +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].ID +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].Name +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].Singer +
    "</td></tr>";
    }
    out += "</table>"
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: I want to read database from server. Console response me "  
Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" @Dexter Huinda

Comment: just try to replace the line that says `var arr = JSON.parse(response)` with `var arr = response` and test again.